# Passing autocomplete value to ajax not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, parameter-passing

I want to show mysql result as html table.My problem come here, the variable value not sending to ajax data (empty).

```
 <form id="oqcform">
    .....
    <input type="text" id="fittest"/>
    <input type="text" id="NIK"/>
    <button id="inputbutton">Input</button>
    </form>
    <div id="qtycheck"></div>

$("#inputbutton").click(function() {
//ajax for show mysql result as html table
var IDnum = $("#NIK").val();
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"process2.php",
        data:"NO="+IDnum+"&action=personalqty",  //problem here NO = empty
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        success: function(result){
                $('#qtycheck').html(result); //echo html table & mysql result
                }
        });
 });
```

at console log:

```
NO:                  --> empty
action:personalqty
```

---

UPDATE

i try to make duplicate value:

```
$("#inputbutton").click(function() {
     $('#fittest').val($('#NIK').val());
     });
```

input value not duplicated.

Comment: when is the `process2.php` request sent? is it on dom ready or on change of the value

Comment: looks like you may have to sent the second ajax request `process2.php` on change event of `#NIK` field

Comment: actually this ajax works fine. but the result is not correct after I check the `NO = ` in my browser console.Actually I want after submit I could get `IDnum` value from `NIK`, then doing ajax process, then html will show the mysql result.

Comment: it cause mysql show the result `WHERE NO = ''`

Comment: data:"NO="+IDnum+"&action=personalqty", remove space after NO

Comment: @nunu: thanks ), try remove space after NO

Comment: maybe error in process2.php? for testing use simple form with action='process2.php' and two inputs: NO and action

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35811/discussion-between-nunu-and-andrey-shatilov)